# Why cant we are able to create chield class object to its own type when constructor method of parent is used to create Object in Java

Tags: java

Step 1: Parent class

```
public class Parent {
    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("parent m2");
    }
}
```

Step 2: Chield class

```
public class Chield  extends Parent{
        public void m1() {
            System.out.println("chield m1");
        }
        public void m2() {
            System.out.println("chield m2");
        }
    }
```

Step 3:-

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String []args) {
                
        Chield c = (Chield) new Parent(); 
        
    }
}
```

//giving me a runtime error
//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.swapnil.Parent cannot be //cast to class com.swapnil.Chield (com.swapnil.Parent and com.swapnil.Chield are in unnamed //module of loader 'app')

Comment: Why do you expect this to work?  Why would a Parent also be a Child?

Answer (score 0):

This won't give you a compile time error as you are type casting and compiler thinks that it is done purposely and it is possible. But it gives runtime error as because it is not possible. parent class can not be casted into child class.